# Using Google Cloud Bigquery to access edx2bigquery: Unable to use cryptographic functions Try installing OpenSSL

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use google cloud to access `edx2bigquery` datasets (https://github.com/mitodl/edx2bigquery). However, I am receiving the `Unable to use cryptographic functions Try installing OpenSSL` error even though I have openssl installed. I am sure I set up my api key correctly. Do you have any idea why I am still receiving this error?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/357

Basicly: I needed to update the oauth2client by using

`pip install oauth2client==1.5.2`